# solve the ODE in $C^1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I'm trying to find a 'unique' continuous solution with continuous first derivative to the second order ODE 
$y''(y'^2-1)=0$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=1$..

I know that from $y''=0$ the solution is $y=x$ which is continuous and has a continuous first derivative. Now for $y'^2-1=0$ how I can show that the solutions here are discontinuous or have discontinuous first derivatives?

Appreciate any help and hint.

Comment: you can set $u=y'$ then your equation becomes
$u' u^2 = u'$.
Integrating you get that $1/3 u^3 = u + c$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but I can't see how this is can be helpful to determine first derivative discontinuous solutions?

Comment: $y'=1\implies y=x$ gives a second path to the same solution, how do you define "unique" for a singular differential equation where solutions can have multiplicities?